# How to capture and port precise audio configuration/driver/package setup from one Linux distro to another?

Tags: arch-linux, kali-linux, audio, portability, microphone

I decided to switch to Linux, so I installed Arch (with xfce4).

Neither speakers, nor mic worked out of the box.
I installed `sof-firmware` and was able to make speakers work, but not the mic.

Meanwhile, I tried launching Kali live USB (it also came with xfce4), and everything was working out of the box--both speakers and mic.

How can I look up what Kali's setup is (which drivers, packages, and setting are being used) for sound, and can I port it easily to Arch (install the appropriate packages and copy config files from Kali to Arch)? I am a complete beginner, so even trivial steps/commands would be appreciated.

Comment: dpkg -l for installed package on kali. Config is under /etc